# Angular JS prevent controller from running on hidden element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-controller

I have this codes

```
.state('fooState', {
    url: '/foo',
    templateUrl: 'path/to/bar.html',
    controller:'parentController'
})

// THIS IS THE bar.html
<div class="sample">
    <div ng-show="bazinga" ng-controller="child1Controller">
        <!-- cool stuff -->
    </div>
    <div ng-show="!bazinga" ng-controller="child2Controller">
        <!-- cool stuff -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it normal that when the first `div` with the controller `child1Controller` is shown, the controller `child2Controller` will also run? How do I prevent a controller from running if it is hidden via `ng-show="false"`? I only need the `parentController` and the `child1Controller` controllers running when the first `div` is visible. Same with when 2nd div is visible, the `parentController` and the `child1Controller` controllers should only the one's running.

Comment: You could also do this with nested states/views...

Comment: So there would be another `<div ui-view>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, using `ng-if` rather than `ng-show` should solve your issue. The difference being that `ng-if` does not render the element to the DOM when it evaluates to false.

Comment: Hi thanks, so how do I exactly do the logic? What will be the value for `ng-if`?

Comment: It's used the same as how you're using ng-show, so literally just swap those out and the values stay the same